# Buoyancy force on a hung object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, buoyancy, fluid-statics

If an object is hung with a cord and it have been embedded in a fluid, then the buoyancy force will reduce the cord tension.What is the formula that governs this reduction ?.

Comment: If the cord is taut then the reduction simply equals the standard buoyancy force (i.e. the weight of the displaced fluid).

Comment: do you mean rigid ?.

Comment: **Eureka!** Did you even search _buoyancy_ before posting? Do a free body diagram and add the buoyancy force upwards.

Comment: I know that !.But am doing a text book exercise and when I've checked the answer ,mine is wrong!.tension and buoyancy force upward and weight downward.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the buoyant force is $F_b = \rho*g*V_d$, where $\rho$ is the density of the fluid and $V_d$ is the volume of the displaced fluid.  Since the object is completely submerged, the displaced volume equals the volume of the sphere.

Judging by your comment, you have summed the forces correctly.  If you posted your work, we could have a better idea of what you have done wrong.